# How to remove rows from data frame without changing its dimension

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to remove rows from my data frame without changing the column name.

I tried it with a sample data frame to remove row 3:

```
> df <- data.frame(v1=c('a', 'b', 'c'))
> df
  v1
1  a
2  b
3  c
> new <- df[!(df$v1=='c'),]
> new
[1] a b
Levels: a b c
```

Where did I do wrong that I didn't get new as:

```
   v1
1  a
2  b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we check the `?Extract`, the default option is

> x[i, j, ... , drop = TRUE]

So, change it to `drop=FALSE` to not drop the dimensions

```
df[!(df$v1=='c'),, drop=FALSE]
#  v1
#1  a
#2  b
```

---

Or as an alternative, `subset` can be used which has `drop=FALSE` by default

```
subset(df, v1=="c")
```

Comment: what does drop= do?

Comment: @hotterthanmath  If you have a single row or single column as a result of subsetting, it will drop the dimensions to convert it to a `vector`

Comment: thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

You also use the `as.data.frame()` to convert it to the `dataframe` like the following :

```
> df <- data.frame(v1=c('a', 'b', 'c'))
> df
  v1
1  a
2  b
3  c
> new <- df[!(df$v1=='c'),]
> new
[1] a b
Levels: a b c


>as.data.frame(new)# use as.data.frame () function
  new
1   a
2   b
```